# Select a campo de otra tabla con clave foránea

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE roles (
    id int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rol varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO `roles` VALUES ('1', 'Moderador'),('2', 'Administrador');

CREATE TABLE users (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password varchar(500),
    rol_id int(2),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (`rol_id`) REFERENCES `roles`(`id`)
);
```

Necesito hacer un select de los campos de la tabla users, pero que en rol_id en vez de mostrarme el campo ID de la tabla roles, me muestre el campo ROL. Intente esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users JOIN roles ON users.rol_id = roles.rol";
```

Pero no funciona.

Saludos

Comment: Está mal el MATCH, o sea todo luego del ON, el usuario id es de campo entero y el rol de roles es de campo VARCHAR. No te va a traer nada porque no hay registros que existan en esa condición que pusiste. En todo caso no bastaría con cambiarlo a `users.rol_id = roles.id` ?

Comment: Entiendo. No puedo probarlo porque el . me tira error de sintaxis. Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Te modifique el join, agregue alias para las tablas y enumere los atributos que queres obtener de la consulta

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.username, u.password, r.rol 
FROM users u, roles r 
WHERE u.rol_id = r.id";
```

Comment: Esta consulta es correcta (si quitas las comillas dobles antes del punto y coma) para lo que pide @fede-liber. Sin embargo, es más legible la solución de @Isanchezo expresada como comentario de la pregunta, porque siempre es más conveniente especificar la fórmula `JOIN, INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN...`, especialente en consultas más complejas

Comment: Estoy intentando mostrar los datos a través de una tabla pero hay un error de sintaxis, que debe ser por el punto.

`<th><?php echo $result -> r.rol ?></th>`

Comment: si, ese punto no va ahi, si quieres pone el codigo que recorre el resultado de la busqueda y te ayudo